# "Assignment Problem" solution question

Tags: algorithm

I was reading through a solution to the assignment problem here:  http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=hungarianAlgorithm

I understand the O(n3) solution), but had a question about the easier O(n4) solution.

Perhaps I misunderstood the notation, but when he goes to modify the weights in step 2 -- why doesn't the weight from w1->j2 increase the same way w2->j1 increases.

Can anyone better explain the notation in the rule defined in

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the two logical symbols are supposed to be "and" and "xor" respectively.  The xor symbol chosen looks more like an inclusive or, that is probably a typo.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or for some of the less confusing alternatives.

With this interpretation, you have the following possibilities:

1. Neither `i` nor `j` is in `V`.  Then you get the first case.
2. `i` is in `V`, but `j` is not.  Then you get the second case.
3. `i` is not in `V`, but `j` is.  Then you get the second case.
4. Both `i` and `j` are in `V`.  Then you get the third case.

As you see, all cases are covered, and there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks -- That completely clears up the confusion in notation.  However, it still leaves my confused as to why in the problem w1--->j2 doesn't fall into the "3rd case" when w2--->j1 does.